# npm install create-react-app unsupported engine error

Tags: node.js, npm, solidity, truffle

Im getting error when I try to npm install create-react-app:

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'hawk@0.10.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '0.8.x' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v20.8.0', npm: '10.2.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'hoek@0.7.6',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '0.8.x' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v20.8.0', npm: '10.2.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
```

Comment: Something seems a little out of date. You don't typically install `create-react-app` as a local package though. Try running `npx create-react-app my-app` or if you still have issues `npx create-react-app@latest my-app`. See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/